# How to solve "! LaTeX Error: File `todonotes.sty' not found" in Linux?

Tags: errors, linux

I'm running Fedora 20 and trying to compile the following simple document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}

\title{Your Paper}

\author{You}

\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

Hello, World!

\end{document}
```

After this I get the error `! LaTeX Error: File todonotes.sty not found` and don't know how to fix it. I use TexMaker and have everything installed, but still get this.

How can I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Did you install `sudo apt-get install texlive-full`. It's a package that installs most common LaTeX modules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By installing the right package that contains todonotes. I'm not a user of Fedora but after a quick search I think you can get todonotes.sty by installing this package (which seems to be a subpackage of texlive, but I don't know how Fedora manage it):

https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/texlive-todonotes

Answer (score 3):

On Debian or Ubuntu you can install the `texlive-latex-extra` package. It is a part of `texlive-full` package which is a lot bigger.

`sudo apt install texlive-latex-extra`